# Magento 2.3.5p2 - Invalid security or form key. Please refresh the page after installing banner slider

Tags: magento2, module, extensions, php-7, banner-slider

I downloaded BannerSlider from [GitHub](https://github.com/Magestore/Bannerslider-Magento2) and pasted the files into the  app> code> Magestore. in the admin panel, it showing the manage options but when I click it says
`Invalid security or form key.`

Please refresh the page.
I tried changing `max input vars` to `10000` in `php.ini` file but no change.

Can anyone help me I am new to Magento I am using `PHP 7.3.2`.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you already tried increasing the max input vars, i recomend you to also:

- Run on your terminal:

  php bin/magento setup:upgrade;
  php bin/magento setup:di:compile;
  php bin/magento cache:clean;
  php bin/magento cache:flush;
- Clear your browser cookies;

Usually this error occurs when magento can't recognize the form key in it's validation, either by not receiving it, or by being invalid.

Comment: it worked but the module was gone

Comment: The module was deleted by someone, or simply disappeared?
I haven't heard of magento deleting anything from setup commands!

Answer (score 0):

Please add following code in your admin controller :

```
protected $request;
protected $formKey;

public function __construct(
\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey $formKey,
\Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request
) {
    $this->request = $request;
    $this->formKey = $formKey;
    $this->request->setParam('form_key', $this->formKey->getFormKey());
    parent::__construct($context);
}
```

Comment: where is this admin controller? which file? I am new to Magento

Comment: try on https://github.com/Magestore/Bannerslider-Magento2/blob/master/Controller/Adminhtml/Slider/Index.php  and https://github.com/Magestore/Bannerslider-Magento2/blob/master/Controller/Adminhtml/Banner/Index.php  file